# ssrs one or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I'm having the error one or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified.  The only thing is i've removed all but one parameter from my report and I have specified the value for that parameter.  My guess is it's still looking for one of the parameter's i deleted from the report.  How do I find that parameter value and get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing reports on the server often does weird things with the parameters on the server. The fix is to delete the report off the server and then deploy a fresh version.

Answer (score 0):

One way this can happen is if you are using Shared Datasets and you pull in DataSets that your report is not using. Each report must define its own version of the parameters for each shared Dataset locally. So if you've included a Dataset as one of your data sources and you have not explicitly defined how this particular report will pass parameters to that Dataset, you'll get this error.